Configure default build and run commands in projectile (on a per-project basis)
In a CMake project, how do I set the default commands to compile or run a project? (e.g. what shows up when I hit C-c p c)?
I know there is a ".projectile" file that can be placed at the project root, but I could not find a documentation of what can be placed in there.

See Ignoring Files in the Projectile documentation. You might also want to read the CMake section.
